# NLog Database Not Being Created

Tags: c#, nlog

I've set-up nlog for the first time, and have multiple locations in there to log... this is the settings I have in my nlog but the table is never created?

```
<target xsi:type="Database"
       name="DatabaseTarget"
       keepConnection="true"
       commandType="Text"
       dbDatabase="IISLogging"
       dbUserName="user"
       dbPassword="password"
       dbHost="111.111.11.1"
       commandText="INSERT INTO [Log] (Logged,Level,LogMessage,Exception,StackTrace,Path,Json,Ip) 
                    VALUES (@Logged, @Level, @Message, @Exception, @StackTrace,@Path,@Json,@Ip)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `nlog.config` is properly filled with correct values of your database provider, You can use installing feature of database target.

```
LogManager.Configuration.Install(new InstallationContext());
```

Example install database target

```
<target xsi:type="Database" name="db"
        connectionStringName="LoggingDatabase">
    <install-command>
        <text>
            <!--
            NOTE: call LogManager.Configuration.Install(new InstallationContext()); 
                  to execute this query.
            -->
            CREATE TABLE ${var:logTableName} (
            Id bigint primary key not null identity(1,1),
            Logged datetime2,
            Level nvarchar(10),
            LogMessage nvarchar(max),
            MessageUid uniqueidentifier,
            MessagePartUid uniqueidentifier,
            MessagePartDataUid uniqueidentifier,
            )
        </text>
        <ignoreFailures>false</ignoreFailures>
    </install-command>
```

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Installing-targets

Also, try internal logger to troubleshoot

```
<nlog internalLogLevel="Debug"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.txt"
      internalLogToConsole="true"
      throwConfigExceptions="true">
    <targets>
```

Comment: That is my confusion.  In my `Startup.cs` I have in my `Configure` method `LogManager.Configuration.Install(new InstallationContext());`  I've specified the DbName in both the variables `name` and `dbDatabase` and I've input this information into the files `Nlog.Dev.config`, `Nlog.Development.config`, `Nlog.Prod.config`

Comment: If the problem is not loading an invalid ```NLog.config```, then activate the NLog InternalLogger